# Order doesn't come

Tags: orders, magento-community, sales-order

I Just Installed fresh Magento Community with Ultimo theme.
And when i tried to place an order it didn't show up in "Reports > Sales > Orders".

Like Nothing in the orders list.

I've got this warning message since installation but i already ignored it.

[image]

any Idea ?

Comment: Do you see it in the database if you query that directly?

Comment: sorry i forgot to check in sales > orders
i was checking Reports>sales>orders

Comment: i dunno how to use reports yet

Comment: Did you find it in Sales > Orders, then?

Comment: yes i Found it 
but i dunno how to solve this tax problem

Comment: I'd do that as a separate question, it's almost certainly unrelated. For that order not coming up in reports, you probably just have to refresh it (where it says "To refresh last day's statistics, click here.")

Comment: The reports are generated via cron, by default daily, at 1am I believe.